# How do I escape a single slash on command line to Git bash?

Tags: command-line-arguments, git-bash, slash

When I do `git` work on Windows, I'm typically using Git bash and I'm having trouble passing in a simple slash to script:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ python --version
Python 2.7.14
$ cat ~/tmp/args
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json

print json.dumps(sys.argv, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
$ ~/tmp/args /
[
  "C:/Users/jpfuntne/tmp/args",
  "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/"
]
$ ~/tmp/args \/
[
  "C:/Users/jpfuntne/tmp/args",
  "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/"
]
$ ~/tmp/args '/'
[
  "C:/Users/jpfuntne/tmp/args",
  "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/"
]
$
```

I can't figure out how to get the slash to not get replaced with `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/`.  I also use Cygwin bash (*GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)*) for regular work on Windows and it doesn't have the same problem there.  So I can work around it but it bugs me that I can't find a solution.

Comment: Here's a method that works: `~/tmp/args //`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ~/tmp/args //
[
  "C:/Users/jpfuntne/tmp/args",
  "/"
]
```